# initial_fail_amount_action not working as expected

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to create a recurring payment plan which allow me to get the user first payment immediately, for doing this I've used the option `setup_fee` setted as `14.99` but for some reason I can't get this working. Infact, the sandbox user that I used for this doesn't have any funds, and the subscription shouldn't be approved just as it happens. These are the payment details:

```
{
    "name": "Monthly Plan",
    "description": "Monthly plan based subscription",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "usage_type": "LICENSED",
    "product_id": "PROD-32M79039A8219464Y",
    "billing_cycles": [
        {
            "frequency": {
                "interval_unit": "MONTH",
                "interval_count": 1
            },
            "tenure_type": "TRIAL",
            "sequence": 1,
            "total_cycles": 1,
            "pricing_scheme": {
                "fixed_price": {
                    "value": "0",
                    "currency_code": "EUR"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "frequency": {
                "interval_unit": "MONTH",
                "interval_count": 1
            },
            "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
            "sequence": 2,
            "total_cycles": 0,
            "pricing_scheme": {
                "fixed_price": {
                    "value": "14.99",
                    "currency_code": "EUR"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "payment_preferences": {
        "auto_bill_outstanding": true,
        "setup_fee": {
            "value": "14.99",
            "currency_code": "EUR"
        },
        "setup_fee_failure_action": "CANCEL",
        "payment_failure_threshold": 0
    },
    "taxes": {
        "percentage": "0",
        "inclusive": false
    },
    "merchant_preferences": {
        "initial_fail_amount_action": "CANCEL",
        "max_fail_attempts": 0
    }
}
```

I've specified `merchant_preferences`, that must cancel the subscription process in the `PayPal` smart buttons process. But this doesn't do anything. The expected behavior:

1. User approve a subscription using the `PayPal` smart buttons
2. The user has no funds so `PayPal` should stop the process as `merchant_preference` configuration
3. If the user has found, then the subscription must be created and the funds must be sent to merchant account in order to activate the subscription in my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What country is the sandbox user, and what funding sources are on the account? Most sandbox users have infinite funds from a default bank account funding source, or a credit card. It does not matter that their PayPal balance is zero.

In general it is not possible to create a PayPal subscription with only a PayPal balance -- a backup funding source is required.

Comment: The country of the user is italian, and the funding source is `Rabobank Nederland` which has 0 as balance, same for PayPal balance

Comment: Well, the bank (or card if there is a card) will be used. You might be able to create a new custom buyer without a bank or card funding source and zero balance -- or delete that bank and any card in www.sandbox.paypal.com , then you'll just get an error during checkout

Comment: I created another customer without any funds nor bank account or credit card. During the checkout the system ask for a card, then I tried to add one of these: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payflow/payflow-pro/payflow-pro-testing/#credit-card-numbers-for-testing and at the end the system return this message: `Your card has been declined. Try another card.` At this point I don't know if I did an error, or the system is working fine

Comment: Those test cards are for Payflow Pro (and specifically Payflow Pro *without* PayPal as the processor) Use sandbox cards if you need to add one https://developer.paypal.com/developer/creditCardGenerator/

Comment: I generated a card using this service: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/creditCardGenerator/ then I signed in the sandbox customer account and added it, buyed the subscription and the system doesn't raised errors... The card doesn't contains any funds, at this point I'm wondering if I did a mistake in the plan definition

Comment: Sandbox cards contain infinite funds. You tested without a card, you got an error, you added a card, no error. This is all the expected behavior.

Comment: Okay, but now I'm wondering how can I test the `initial_fail_amount` behavior, is there any way to add a card without funds?

Comment: Well the initial_fail_amount does not refer to the setup_fee, it refers to the first actual cycle billing.  What you can do is set up a subscription profile and then remove the card from the account and make sure there are no other funding sources on that account. That might work.

Comment: Is there any guideline to setup a subscription profile?

Comment: Guideline? No. You decide what you want. The documentation is https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/